# How to select randomly 2 rows by using join 2 or more times

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have 3 tables:

```
  News      |      Categories      |      News_in_cat
   id       |          id          |          id
  title     |         name         |        news_id
            |                      |        cat_id
```

The goal is to make mySql select 1 random category from Categories table, then, to look in News_in_cat table and to return 2 random news from selected category from News table.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: SELECT * FROM news
JOIN (SELECT cat_id FROM news_in_cateogory ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) x
WHERE news.id = x.cat_id
I'm trying in phpMyAdmin right now, I have no idea how to realise this, that's why I'm askin here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM News_in_cat AS nic
(SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY RAND() limit 1) AS t
ON t.id = nic.cat_id
INNER JOIN News AS n 
ON n.id = nic.news_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Thank's, this worked. But is there a mysql way to make sql select another category if in a certain category is just 1 post? I mean without using php, this will be very useful.

Comment: Making this inner query something like : `(SELECT * FROM News_in_cat GROUP BY cat_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as t`

Comment: Getting 0 results. Trying to fix it.

Comment: My query looks like this now:
SELECT * FROM news_in_cat AS nic
JOIN (SELECT * FROM news_in_cat GROUP BY cat_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as t
ON t.id = nic.cat_id
INNER JOIN news AS n 
ON n.id = nic.news_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 2

Comment: SELECT * FROM news_in_cat AS nic JOIN (SELECT cat_id as id FROM news_in_cat GROUP BY cat_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as t ON t.id = nic.cat_id INNER JOIN news AS n ON n.id = nic.news_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2